# Looking for rules to a card game called "Wild Cards"

Tags: identify-this-game

This game is played with several tables of four in which winning partners in one round move to new table.  Wild cards/rules change with each round.  It's great for getting to know people.

I lost my set of rules

Comment: Not a card game, but Bunco looks like it has a similar mechanic: http://boardgames.lovetoknow.com/Bunco_Game_Rules

Comment: I found references to two games called Wild Cards, neither of which seem to match your description. There is [a 2005 game] for 2-6 players and [a 2013 game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/173358/wild-cards) that are just cards with rules for games on them. I cannot find a reference to a more recent game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear. This sounds like it's just describing a rotating play format - like speed dating, but with cards and no dating. (And if that's all there is to it, I'm not sure what the missing rules *would be.*) There's no actual board or card game being asked about here as far as I can tell, and if there is, I can't tell what it is in order to try to identify it or what its rules would be (it's just "rules change each round", which could have been an initiative of organisers of the meet-up event).

Comment: Is this game played with regular (French) [playing cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_playing_cards)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after commenting above, I discovered that you can play Bunco using cards instead of dice.  Check out some of the card-based variants on this page - maybe one of them will be close enough (at least in spirit) to the game that you remember.

http://www.ehow.com/info_12101194_bunco-card-games.html